# windows 7 error 1001 installUtlLib.dll

Tags: windows-7

This is my first post here and I don't know if this is the right section ...
During the last 2 days, I encountered an error when trying to install a program that I download from the web (attached an image)
and suddenly another program refuses to work when I try to install it such as window installer (that website recommend to use as a solution)
iv searched for another solution across the web but I didn't find except for reinstalling a new windows that i don't want to do ....any help plz?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Technically, any installer worth it's weight will have an installation log somewhere (most likely in the %temp% folder). If you can find it and investigate it, it should give you more information about the error (in your case, we're trying to identify which file cannot be found).